# What is the complexity(Big O) of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I have an array of n numbers from 0 to n-1.

```
int func(Integer[]array){
    int res = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        for (int y = x; y > Math.max(x - 1000, 0) ; y--) {
            res = res + array[y];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

O(n), O(n^2), O(n^1/5), O(log n)

I think it's **O(n^2)**. I'm right?

Comment: Talk us through your reasoning. How did you arrive at this result? Also, is this homework?

Comment: Indeed, it's alright to ask time complexity questions but it requires an effort to explain why you've come to a specific conclusion, and it's generally not a good idea to copy/paste homework questions.

Comment: One obvious line of reasoning is that there are two loops so you can eliminate all the <= O(n) complexities, leaving only O(n^2) .

Comment: thanks, yes, in the worst case I have n^2 comparisons

Comment: @cs95 It is possible to have two loops that will work out to O(n) or even O(log n) time depending on how those loops are structured.

Comment: @templatetypedef I should've clarified I'm making that assumption because the outer loop is obviously O(n) but you are correct. :-)

Comment: The inner loop is not O(n), it's O(1) because it loops at most 1000 times.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Paul's comment is correct. The inner loop only runs at constant time. Therefore, the time complexity is just O(N) for the outer loop.

The algorithm also runs at constant memory O(1).

Comment: The inner loop executes at most 1000 times, so is O(1) not O(n).

Comment: @PaulHankin  Your comment's been taken into account